# curl post using urllib2

Tags: json, python-2.7, curl, urllib2, apache-nifi

I want to do `curl -i -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -u username:password -X POST -d @test.json http://dev-nifi01-ambari1:80/api/v1/clusters/test-nifi/hosts/hostname` in python with following code where contents of the test.json is `{"blueprint" : "recommended","host_group" : "nifi-hg-1"}`

```
import os
import urllib
import urllib2
import base64
url = "http://dev-nifi01-ambari1:80/api/v1/clusters/test-nifi/hosts/" + hostname
data = {"blueprint" : "recommended","host_group" : "nifi-hg-1"}
req = urllib2.Request(url, data=urllib.urlencode(data)) #also tried urllib2.Request(url, data=json.dumps(data))
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
req.add_header('X-Requested-By','ambari')
req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

But getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Any idea what's wrong here ?

Comment: Add "X-Requested-By" to headers ?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: If `data` is json don't `urlencode` it, pass it as a string

Comment: In that case `req = urllib2.Request(url, data)` I get `TypeError: must be string or buffer, not dict1`

Comment: Yes, use a string : `data = '{"blueprint" : "recommended","host_group" : "nifi-hg-1"}'`

Comment: `data = '{"blueprint" : "recommended","host_group" : "nifi-hg-1"}'
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)` gave me same error.